# InDesign: Updating ToC causes All Document Text to Disappear

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am using a template supplied by the service bureau. After adding 200+ pages of body text, I returned to the table of contents, and updated it. The red box (overset text) appeared. The next page was blank, containing only a blue hidden crosshatch (#) character. I clicked on the red box, got a loaded arrow, and clicked on the page with the blue crosshatch. The ToC updated properly. I went through the document where there were a few unneeded blank pages and deleted them. Now when I update the Table of Contents, all the text in the entire document disappears. If I undo that action, the ToC and the rest of the document's pages reappear, but the ToC isn't updated and contains entries with incorrect page numbers. How can I fix this?

Update: Apparently a ToC has to be within its own "story" in an InDesign file. I think, though I'm not sure, that the "story" was demarcated by the blue crosshatch character(#). In the version of the file that's giving me problems, now there is only one blue crosshatch at the end of the file. If there was a way to insert the blue crosshatch at the end of the ToC this might solve the problem but I have no idea as to how to do do this.

Comment: Does the copy get deleted or did it somehow get shoved into a hidden box? If you search for a text string you know exists in the copy, what happens?

Comment: The body text is deleted. Searching for a word contained only in the body text yields, "No Match" under search.

Answer (score 2):

It's well late, but maybe this might help someone else. Your TOC was probably threaded to connect to the rest of the document, it needs to be in a separate story to the rest of your document.

Updating the TOC has the effect of starting from the top of the text frame containing the TOC, and *overwriting everything in that thread* with the new TOC.
If your TOC is followed by some empty spaces, you probably won't see it's been deleted. If your TOC is followed by 200+ pages of body text, well, that's something you'd notice being gone.

### TL;DNR

Make the TOC in a separate text frame, and don't thread it to anything else.